# Одновременное редактирование блока верстки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, visual-studio-code, sublime-text

Смотрел [FlEXBOX.Примеры верстки на flex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gu40PFzOHI) c 2:45-3:15. Там производился одновременный ввод элементов li внутри блока

```html
<ul class="hi__list">
  <li>У тебя все получится!</li>
  <li>Никогда не сдавайся!</li>
  <li>Сегодня ты уже знаешь больше чем вчера!</li>
  <li>Спасибо тебе за поддержку!</li>  
</ul>
```

Подскажите все комбинации клавиш, которые использовались для выполнения этого действия (включая выделение), в Vs Code и в Sublime.

Comment: В разных редакторах разные горячие клавиши... Точно знаю, что  в sublime && vsCode это штатная функция

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/175747/

Comment: @AndreyFedorov в статье habr.com/ru/post/175747 нет сокращений, которые использовались в моем видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gu40PFzOHI с 2:45-3:15.

Comment: @Air можно конкретнее.

Comment: В sublime горячие клавиши `ctrl+alt + клавиши верх и вниз`, в vscode штатное сочетание клавиш не помню, я у ся изменил, но поищи строку `добавить курсор выше и ниже`. Vscode  надо нажать `ctrl+k+s` и откроется раздел сочетание клавиш

Comment: Кстати, я если честно не помню, может @AndreyFedorov, прав и это фишка от `emmet`, в `vscode` `emmet` установлен штатно, а  `sublime` его не было, щас не знаю, года 4  `sublime` не использую. Так что если что придется `emmet` установить